# Question about grepl in R (string with +)

Tags: r, grepl

I am using grepl in R, but I have a problem with it.
When the string contains "+", it has an error. The error is shown below:

```
x <- "1.37E+11" 
grepl("1.37E+",x)  #TRUE
grepl("1.37E+11",x)  #FALSE
grepl("+11",x)  #TRUE
grepl("E+11",x)  #FALSE
```

When both in front of and after the + sign have words, the result is FALSE even though it should be TRUE. I am not sure why. Please help me. Thank you guys so much!! : )

Comment: `+` is a reserved character meaning 1 or more in regular expressions. You can use `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl` which will escape that.